# How can make a data join and show it in listview in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, listview, join, inner-join

im new in vb.net, can anybody help me in making a join and transfer it in listview.
for example:

table name userInfo
userID
fname
lname

table name accountInfo
userID
activness

i want to show in join is..
userID
fname
lname
activness

then transfer in listview .

here is my code:

```
    Dim connincomeDivision As SqlConnection
    Dim cmdincomeDivision As SqlCommand
    Dim daincomeDivision As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dsincomeDivision As DataSet
    Dim itemcollincomeDivision(100) As String

    connincomeDivision = New SqlConnection("Data Source =ENTITY-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=chosenlandrealtyDB; integrated security = true;")
    Dim strQincomeDivision As String = String.Empty
    strQincomeDivision = "SELECT userID,fName,lName FROM userInfo JOIN account ON userInfo.userID = account.userID"

    cmdincomeDivision = New SqlCommand(strQincomeDivision, connincomeDivision)
    daincomeDivision = New SqlDataAdapter(cmdincomeDivision)
    dsincomeDivision = New DataSet
    daincomeDivision.Fill(dsincomeDivision, "userInfo")
    Dim iincomeDivision As Integer = 0
    Dim jincomeDivision As Integer = 0
    ' adding the columns in ListView

    'Now adding the Items in Listview
    For iincomeDivision = 0 To dsincomeDivision.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        For jincomeDivision = 0 To dsincomeDivision.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            itemcollincomeDivision(jincomeDivision) = dsincomeDivision.Tables(0).Rows(iincomeDivision)(jincomeDivision).ToString()
        Next
        Dim lviincomeDivision As New ListViewItem(itemcollincomeDivision)
        Me.ListView2.Items.Add(lviincomeDivision)
    Next
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE :))